# How to launch spark 3.0.0 kubernetes workload without kerberos?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kerberos

It seems that on spark 3.0.0 when I do a spark submit with kubernetes it require kerberos, I use the same spark submit that was working great in 2.4.5
I get this error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/07/04 08:17:51 INFO SparkKubernetesClientFactory: Auto-configuring K8S client using current context from users K8S config file
20/07/04 08:17:51 INFO KerberosConfDriverFeatureStep: You have not specified a krb5.conf file locally or via a ConfigMap. Make sure that you have the krb5.conf locally on the driver image.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
```

To be more specific, I don't want to use kerberos

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found, you need to specify a spark_uid at image build step.

Comment: Hi @erich, I am facing the exact same issue. Dockerfile shipped with spark 3.0 already conatins spark_uid = 185, but still I am getting the issue. Please let me know how did you solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

either you handle this id ( 185) at os level, or you can comment it in the dockerfile but you will be root....
Eric

Comment: Thanks a lot @erich. Commenting out the USER worked (though it runs as root as you mentioned).