# Spark submit fails on Kubernetes (EKS) with "invalid null input: name"

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to run spark sample SparkPi docker image on EKS. My Spark version is 3.0.
I created spark serviceaccount and role binding. When I submit the job, there is error below:

```sh
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862635502Z Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: failure to login
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862756537Z  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:841)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862772672Z  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:777)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862777401Z  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:650)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862788327Z  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2412)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862792294Z  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.8628321Z    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2412)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862836906Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicDriverFeatureStep.configurePod(BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala:119)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862907673Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesDriverBuilder.$anonfun$buildFromFeatures$3(KubernetesDriverBuilder.scala:59)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862917119Z  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86294845Z   at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862964245Z  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.862979665Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesDriverBuilder.buildFromFeatures(KubernetesDriverBuilder.scala:58)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863055425Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:98)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863060434Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:221)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863096062Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863103831Z  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2539)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863163804Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863168546Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:188)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863194449Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863218817Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863246594Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863252341Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863277236Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863314173Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863319847Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863653699Z Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863660447Z  at com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863663683Z  at com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:133)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863667173Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863670199Z  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863673467Z  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86367674Z   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863680205Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863683401Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86368671Z   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863689794Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863693081Z  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863696183Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863698579Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863700844Z  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:815)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863703393Z  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:777)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86370659Z   at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:650)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863709809Z  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2412)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863712847Z  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863716102Z  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2412)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863719273Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.features.BasicDriverFeatureStep.configurePod(BasicDriverFeatureStep.scala:119)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86372651Z   at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesDriverBuilder.$anonfun$buildFromFeatures$3(KubernetesDriverBuilder.scala:59)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863728947Z  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863731207Z  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863733458Z  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863736237Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesDriverBuilder.buildFromFeatures(KubernetesDriverBuilder.scala:58)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863738769Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:98)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863742105Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:221)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863745486Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863749154Z  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2539)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863752601Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:215)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863756118Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:188)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863759673Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863762774Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863765929Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86376906Z   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863792673Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863797161Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863799703Z  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863802085Z 
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863804184Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863806454Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863808705Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863811134Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863815328Z  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863817575Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863819856Z  at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.863829171Z  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:815)
2020-07-05T12:19:40.86385963Z   ... 24 more
```

My deployments are:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: helios
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: spark
  namespace: helios
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: spark-role-binding
  namespace: helios
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: spark
    namespace: helios
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: spark-pi
  namespace: helios
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark-pi
          image: <registry>/spark-pi-3.0
          command: [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
            --master k8s://https://<EKS_API_SERVER> \
            --deploy-mode cluster \
            --name spark-pi \
            --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=helios
            --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
            --conf spark.executor.memory=2G \
            --conf spark.executor.cores=2 \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<registry>/spark-pi-3.0 \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
            --conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy
            local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar"
          ]
      serviceAccountName: spark
      restartPolicy: Never
```

The docker image is created using OOTB dockerfile provided in Spark installation.

```
docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

**SOLUTION**
Finally it worked out after I comment the below line from docker file.

```
USER ${spark_uid}
```

Though, now, container is running as root but at least it is working.

Comment: Looks like some missing user credentials for Hadoop? `at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:815)`

Comment: Hi @Victor, where to provide these? SparkPi java example file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked out after I comment the below line from docker file.

USER ${spark_uid}
Though, now, container is running as root but at least it is working.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing the k8s job.

Hadoop is failing to find a username for the user. You can see the problem by running `whoami` in the container, which yields `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 185`. The spark image `entrypoint.sh` contains [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cef665004847c4cc2c5b0be9ef29ea5510c0922e/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh#L30) to add the user to `/etc/passwd`, which sets a username. However `command` bypasses the `entrypoint.sh`, so instead you should use `args` like so:

```
      containers:
        - name: spark-pi
          image: <registry>/spark-pi-3.0
      args: [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
            --master k8s://https://10.100.0.1:443 \
            --deploy-mode cluster ..."
      ]
```

Comment: Sneaky problem with a very elegant fix. Thank you.

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you are missing the ServiceAccount/AWS role credentials so that your job can connect to the EKS cluster.

I recommend you set up [*fine-grained IAM roles for service accounts*](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/).

Basically, you would have something like this (after you set up the roles in AWS):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-serviceaccount-Role1
  name: spark
  namespace: helios
```

Then your job would look something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: spark-pi
  namespace: helios
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark-pi
          image: <registry>/spark-pi-3.0
          command: [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
            --master k8s://https://<EKS_API_SERVER> \
            --deploy-mode cluster \
            --name spark-pi \
            --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=helios
            --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
            --conf spark.executor.memory=2G \
            --conf spark.executor.cores=2 \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<registry>/spark-pi-3.0 \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
            --conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy
            local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar" ]
          env: 
          - name: AWS_ROLE_ARN
            value: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-serviceaccount-Role1
          - name: AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
            value: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount
              name: aws-iam-token
              readOnly: true
      serviceAccountName: spark
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Hi Rico, thanks for this, I will try it out. One question though what will my IAM role have?

Comment: I would start with a role that has full EKS permissions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html#create-service-role

Comment: Hi, I am still getting the same issue. I had a Role ARN having AmazonEKSClusterPolicy attached to it. I put this in ServiceAccount annotation and as well as in spark submit env as you mentioned. Also, I also need to mount a volume
  volumes:
      - name: aws-iam-token
        emptyDir: {} 
But, I am still getting the same error. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Rico, Can you please help here. I tried with Role but still the same error. Is there anything more that I can give a try?

Comment: Can you actually give your role full permissions to see if it's an issue with the Role?

Comment: I tried with my role (which has full permission) but still the same issue.  Another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726949/how-to-launch-spark-3-0-0-kubernetes-workload-without-kerberos/62751278#comment111107860_62751278) on this suggests to use spark_uid but my dockerfile already has it.

Comment: I'd focus on this error `invalid null input: name` is there somewhere in the configs where you have that?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you completely. I am just trying to deploy sample spark pi that is shipped with installation using the above deployment configs

Comment: Check for this string `invalid null input: name` in the original log file that you posted

Comment: Yes, it is there in log file. Sorry, still did not get you. Error indicates that I am missing "name". How to provide it? SHould it be part of my code?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the configs in the container image.

Comment: default entrypoint.sh ahs this: # If there is no passwd entry for the container UID, attempt to create one
if [ -z "$uidentry" ] ; then
    if [ -w /etc/passwd ] ; then
        echo "$myuid:x:$myuid:$mygid:${SPARK_USER_NAME:-anonymous uid}:$SPARK_HOME:/bin/false" >> /etc/passwd
    else
        echo "Container ENTRYPOINT failed to add passwd entry for anonymous UID"
    fi
fi

Comment: What about spark configs in the container?

Comment: I think you can debug it by creating a shell container with the same container image and then issue the job from there...

Comment: I think another thing you can try. is to add a securityContext to your pod spec so that it forces the container to run as the default user that the container image runs as. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: Finally it worked out after I comment the USER from docker file. Though, now, it is running as root but at least it is working. Thanks for all your help @Rico

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding into submit container

```
export SPARK_USER=spark3
```

without comment line  `USER ${spark_uid}`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and was able to resolve it by specifying `runAsUser` on the pod spec without having to modify the spark docker image.

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 65534
  runAsGroup: 65534
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, fixed it by adding

`RUN echo 1000:x:1000:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false >> /etc/passwd`
line in the last part Spark Dockerfile

```
RUN echo '1000:x:1000:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false' >> /etc/passwd
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
USER ${spark_uid}
```

so full dockerfile looks like this

`cat spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile`

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
ARG ROOT_CONTAINER=ubuntu:focal

FROM ${ROOT_CONTAINER}

ARG openjdk_version="8"
ARG spark_uid=1000

# Before building the docker image, first build and make a Spark distribution following
# the instructions in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html.
# If this docker file is being used in the context of building your images from a Spark
# distribution, the docker build command should be invoked from the top level directory
# of the Spark distribution. E.g.:
# docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .
RUN apt-get update --yes && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    "openjdk-${openjdk_version}-jre-headless" \
    ca-certificates-java 

RUN apt-get install --yes software-properties-common 
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip \
        python3-distutils \
        python3-setuptools
RUN pip install pyspark==3.2.0

RUN set -ex && \
    sed -i 's/http:\/\/deb.\(.*\)/https:\/\/deb.\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ln -s /lib /lib64 && \
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt install -y -qq bash tini libc6 libpam-modules krb5-user libnss3 procps  && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/examples && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir && \
    mkdir -p /etc/metrics/conf/ && \
    mkdir -p /opt/hadoop/ && \
    touch /opt/spark/RELEASE && \
    rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su && \
    chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* 

COPY jars /opt/spark/jars
COPY bin /opt/spark/bin
COPY sbin /opt/spark/sbin
COPY kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh /opt/
COPY kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/decom.sh /opt/
COPY examples /opt/spark/examples
COPY kubernetes/tests /opt/spark/tests
COPY data /opt/spark/data
COPY conf/prometheus.yaml /etc/metrics/conf/


ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
RUN chmod g+w /opt/spark/work-dir
RUN chmod a+x /opt/decom.sh

RUN  mkdir -p /opt/spark/logs && \
     chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/spark/logs

RUN echo '1000:x:1000:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false' >> /etc/passwd
RUN cat /etc/passwd
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]
# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
USER ${spark_uid}
```

Build spark-docker image

`sudo  ./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <my_docker_repo>/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2-gcs -t <tag_number>  build`