# Spark Submit fails on Kubernetes using Spark Bitnami Docker image getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name"

Tags: python, docker, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

I know this question was already partly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741285/spark-submit-fails-on-kubernetes-eks-with-invalid-null-input-name) but the answer provided didn't help further.

I'm using the image `bitnami/spark:3.2.1` and the following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit 
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=my-image 
--master k8s://my-endpoint 
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=my-spark-sv-acc
--conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master-svc:7077 
--deploy-mode cluster 
local:///opt/bitnami/my-main.py
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: failure to login
...
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
```

Also, when I am trying to exec into the container, I get `"I have no name!"` as user logging into the container. I have set up a serviceAccount for my spark bitnami helm chart and I also set runAsUser to 1001.

Any suggestion what I could try to fix this issue? I could also run as root, however because of security reason in the kubernetes cluster, I would like to not do that.

Thank you!